# GraphView in Runnable graphing a singular line

Tags: android, runnable, android-graphview

I have a `GraphView` from the following [GitHub library](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView).

When I use their demonstration of `GraphView RealTimeGraph`, I get it all to work fine and dandy except for one caveat. It is drawing a line based off of all previous data. I.e. it is finding a trendline and drawing a single straight line; when it should be drawing a line from the previously-appended data to the newly-appended data.

Relevant code:

```
public void pauseGraphUI() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimer1);
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimer2);
}

public void updateGraphUI() {
    mTimer1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            globalData.getGraphViewSeries().resetData(
                    new GraphViewData[] {
                            new GraphViewData(1, getRandom()),
                            new GraphViewData(2, getRandom()),
                            new GraphViewData(3, getRandom()),
                            new GraphViewData(4, getRandom()),
                            new GraphViewData(5, getRandom()),
                            new GraphViewData(6, getRandom()) });
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer1, 500);

    mTimer2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            globalData
                    .setGraph2LastXValue(globalData.getGraph2LastXValue() + 1);
            globalData.getGraphViewSeries().appendData(
                    new GraphViewData(globalData.getGraph2LastXValue(),
                            getRandom()), true, 10);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer2, 1000);
}
```

GlobalData is just a `Singleton` class that stores some information I want.

I've attached an image describing my problem further.

[image: graphing a single line after 800 passes...]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem; I forgot to implement

```
graphView.setViewPort(3, 6);
```

The `setViewPort` restricts the window to a specific amount of data.